# ammonia, methylammonia, dimethylammonia, trimethylammonia reactions

Tags: physical-chemistry, bond

Perhaps a "basic" question (pun intended), but I have a few questions about the reactivity of ammonia and its methylated cousins.  I come from an engineering background, essentially I use a process in which thermally cracked ammonia releases its nitrogen atom to a surface under temperature.  I suppose in principle any of the other 3 molecules, with 1,2 or 3 methyl groups could do the same.  However, could I definitely determine whether they would do so at higher or lower temperature?  Essentially, is it as simple as comparing the the C-N bond vs N-H bond energy, or more involved? Would steric factors of the N ability to "see" the surface be involved? Finally, would attempting to do this in solution versus in gas state change anything significantly?  Thanks for any pointers and/or literature refs!

Comment: Some other factors to consider: What happens to the H of $\ce{NH3}$? It may diffuse through the surface, $\ce{CH3}$ won't. The hydrocarbon species involved may poison the catalyst (if there is one) or just deposit on the surface. Finally, I am not sure that thermal cracking of these compounds is possible in solution - I would assume temperature are too high for that.

Comment: Great considerations.  This process is under high vac conditions, ~ 1e-6 to 1e-5 torr, and the surface/subsurface already has hydrogen impurities, so we don't think too much more gets in.  The H likely forms H2. Similar with CH3, although surface residue is not an issue, we could remove later.  This isnt a catalytic reaction per se, what I would like to determine is if any of the methylated versions would more effectively "drive" N into a N deficient structure.  Valid point about temperature in solution, so lets stick to low pressure gaseous.

Comment: Sounds sensible, in the end, you may not get an answer without an experiment. I suggest you look into the conditions of the Haber-Bosch process of ammonia formation for similarities to your conditions. I still suspect the surface may act as a catalyst.

Comment: Right... In my case this is a treatment for the surface, not a gas phase process, so I didn't think of the surface as a catalyst...but I guess that's a small detail, and maybe just wrong.